# In FreeBSD's pkg, which actions mark a package as non-automatic

Tags: package-management, freebsd

I'm trying to keep my packages up-to-date and unused packages off my system. `pkg` has a feature called `autoremove` that will prune unused installed packages that were installed to fulfill dependencies. Internally, it stores this in a flag named `automatic`. Which operations with `pkg`, `portinstall`, `portupgrade`, and `portmaster` would make a package non-automatic?

Comment: Why do you want this? What is the usecase?

Comment: I'm selectively upgrading packages with `portupgrade`, and I'm making sure upgrading some library won't mark it as non-automatic so it can still be autoremoved.

Comment: I don't use `portupgrade` but I've a simple suggestion: upgrade only ONE `automatic`-installed library and check it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 pkg set -A 0 myPackage-1.2.3_4
```

Or use `-A 1` to mark it as automatic.

Also, `pkg query -a "%o %a"` will list all of the packages and their automatic-ness. Or RTFM `pkg-query` for examples of how to list just the automatic or non-automatic packages.